# How to track the updated values from an application form and keep track in a a history table

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

I am working in .net mvc application. i need to keep track of changed values in every column. I have created a historical table. if someone changes firstname , I need to track it like firstname changed from smith to john. what is the best approach to keep these changes

Comment: You don't need to do this yourself; SQLServer has various options for tracking changes built in

Comment: I think [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) can help you

Comment: Thanks Caius, But I think we need admin rights and SQL server Agent running.?